# Webcam/Flash not detecting in Facebook

Tags: flash, webcam, facebook

I wanna use my webcam to click photos but it wont detect nor show the pop up to give it access in flash

here is a video

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1331696/Facebook%20Flash%20Webvam.ogv

its stuck there foreever :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link on [Macromedia's site](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) to give permissions to the site